# Computed column property is wrong on view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, calculated-columns

When you have a table with a computed column, `is_computed` property on view: `sys.columns` gives correct results

```sql
SELECT * 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('some_table')
        AND is_computed = 1
--returns result
```

But when you are referencing the same column in a view, that column is not marked as `is_computed` anymore.

```sql
SELECT * 
    FROM sys.columns 
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('some_view_with_computed_column_from_table_in_select_list')
        AND is_computed = 1
--do not return it anymore
```

`sp_refreshView` works great for other metadata like is_nullable, length, and so on, but not for is_computed...

Maybe anyone has solved such a problem already?

I have tried already an approach where I get property from a table directly, it works but it's quite slow:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 c.is_computed
        FROMsys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('select * from ' + QUOTENAME(@viewname), null, 1) as d 
        INNER JOIN dbo.sviw_Database_Columns as c
            ON d.source_table collate database_default = c.object_name
            AND d.source_column collate database_default = c.column_name
            AND C.column_name = @colum_name
            AND d.name collate database_default = c.column_name
        WHEREd.is_hidden = 0 AND c.is_computed = 1
```

Also was thinking to have some async job to maintain this property somewhere or just having this in DDL trigger, but maybe there could be some more elegant solution to this?

Comment: What about base table column default values and check constraints? Are those returned for a view too?

Comment: Ideally, don't write code that needs to know which column(s) are computed, whether you're accessing a table vs a view, etc. In general, the database structure should be able to change without breaking application code provided it still produces the same logical results. Which is a long way to say, why are you writing code that *cares* whether a column is computed or not?

Comment: Try to use formula inside of the query instead of computed column.

Comment: We are maintaining a framework that should make developers' life easy. is_computed property is not insertable and we have data tables where you can copy data from one table to another with just copy-paste, so is_computed columns are removed from paste content automatically. We have many apps/solutions and all of them are depenedant on this functionality. An option would be for each developer to fix it, but it would be additional things he needs to care about.

Comment: A Computed Column is *specifically* a type of column in a table. A `VIEW` can't have computed column, because it's not a table.

Comment: So are you trying to `INSERT` into `VIEW`s @ModestasDromantas ? Why?

Comment: For reference `is_computed` is always false, even if the calculation is directly in the view. `IDENTITY` does come through though, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=621d6b97fe72ab98cc110b28175b35fd

Comment: In most cases, we specify view, from where to get table data and table/view which one to use to update it. But it happens that the table is not specified and we use view for all operations, where we remove identity, computed, and other types of things and if a view is not complex, it allows inserts/updates. This would not be the case if there would be several apps, but we have a framework and lots of developers are using it... From the above answers, I understand that the only way would be just to calculate and store that metadata somewhere... Thanks, everyone for your insights :)

Comment: _is_computed property is not insertable_ But it is if the view (or table) has an instead-of trigger.

Comment: [duplicate on Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/607401/is-computed-property-on-view-is-not-correct.html) It is a waste of time and effort to independently post the same question on multiple forums

Comment: @SMor Sorry. Noted.